# How to combine three string columns to one which have Nan values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
   A    B     C    
0 NaN   NaN   cat
1 dog   NaN   NaN   
2 NaN   cat   NaN   
3 NaN   NaN   dog
```

I would like to add a colunm with the value that doesnt have the `NaN` value. So that:

```
   A    B     C    D
0 NaN   NaN   cat  cat
1 dog   NaN   NaN  dog 
2 NaN   cat   NaN  cat 
3 NaN   NaN   dog  dog
```

would it be using an `lambda` function? or `fillna`? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) chained

```
df['D'] = df.A.combine_first(df.B).combine_first(df.C)
```

alternatively, forward fill and pick the last column

```
df['D'] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]

# specifying the columns explicitly:
df['D'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].ffill(1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Comment: thanks! the combine_first worked as I realise I had to specify column names. Great!

Comment: You can also use ffill if you need to get the first non null value from a specific list of columns. See updated answer

Comment: thanks alot. And if I had a similar problem from a row point of view would that be a different process all together giver you are "stacking on top" instead of combining?

Answer (score 4):

Please try

```
df['D']=df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went with the `combine_first` method as I realise I had to specify column names (I have some other columns in the df as well which I should have noted).

Answer (score 4):

Let's try `bfill`:

```
df['D'] = df.bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN  cat  cat
1  dog  NaN  NaN  dog
2  NaN  cat  NaN  cat
3  NaN  NaN  dog  dog
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went with the `combine_first` method as I realise I had to specify column names (I have some other columns in the df as well which I should have noted).

Comment: `df[['A','B','C']].bfill(1).iloc[:,0]`?

Answer (score 4):

I would go with `bfill` or `ffill` on axis=1 here as QuangHoang suggests, however if there is 1 column having values always , another alternative with `df.isna` , `df.dot` and `df.lookup`:

```
df['D'] = df.lookup(df.index,df.notna().dot(df.columns))
print(df)
```

---

```
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN  cat  cat
1  dog  NaN  NaN  dog
2  NaN  cat  NaN  cat
3  NaN  NaN  dog  dog
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went with the `combine_first` method as I realise I had to specify column names (I have some other columns in the df as well which I should have noted).

Answer (score 4):

Try something new

```
df = df.join(df.groupby(['D']*df.shape[1],axis=1).first())
df
Out[44]: 
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN  cat  cat
1  dog  NaN  NaN  dog
2  NaN  cat  NaN  cat
3  NaN  NaN  dog  dog
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went with the `combine_first` method as I realise I had to specify column names (I have some other columns in the df as well which I should have noted).

Answer (score 1):

[`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) with [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) works too:

```
df['D'] = df.T.melt()['value'].dropna().to_numpy()
>>> df
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN  cat  cat
1  dog  NaN  NaN  dog
2  NaN  cat  NaN  cat
3  NaN  NaN  dog  dog
```